# ANDROID PLACE_PICKER (builder.build(context)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Basically I am trying to implement a PLACE_PICKER for Android and I am getting this confusing error here:

```
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

The error is coming in line 4:" (builder.build(context), " and I have no idea why, I am getting this down below it as an error:
Unhandled exception: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException, com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException.

Been going around this for ages...any help?

Comment: It looks like you have an older version of Google Play Services installed on your device or emulator than you are compiling your app with.  Can you check the version installed, and compare it with the version that you are compiling with?

Comment: Well I've updated my dependency to the latest : 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' and I'm still having no luck...(builder.build(context), is still the issue.

Comment: Well that would just increase the chances of running into this problem.  Add the code in the answer I just posted, you should get a prompt to upgrade.  Once you upgrade Google Play Services, it should work for you!  The code in the answer will make it so that your app handles the error gracefully in the case that users of your app have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the main issue is that you're running with an older version of Google Play Services.  So in order for it to work for you, you will need to update the version of Google Play Services that is installed on your device or emulator.

This also suggests that you don't have any code that checks if the version required is present on the device, and this is something that you should definitely add, since users in the field may run into the same issue.

The framework provides an easy way to add a prompt to the user to update Google Play Services if the version currently on the device is older than the one required by your app.

Here is a simple example that I just got working.

First, create a member variable `status`:

```
int status;
```

Then, in `onCreate()` of your Activity, check if Google Play Services are available.  If not, then show the dialog that will prompt the user to upgrade:

```
    status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    100).show();
        } 
    }
```

Then, when you want to show the PlacePicker, ensure that `status` indicates that Google Play Services are available.  You may want to also give some indication to the user (add an `else` here) if this condition is not met (also note the extra try/catch).

```
           if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 199;
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                Context context = this;
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

One more thing you could also add would be to re-check the status in `onActivityResult()` to see if the user has updated Google Play Services.
This is also where you would get the result of the PlacePicker dialog:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 100){
        status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    }
    if (requestCode == 199){

        //process Intent......
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @EuanCantley At first I incorrectly thought you were using a Fragment, so the answer was in "Fragment mode".  I just updated the answer, since it looks like you're actually using an Activity.

Comment: An absolute gentleman you are, that works perfectly, thank you kind sir. :) Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For Fragment

```
           try {
                int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            }catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```