# Google Play Services - out of date API 23

Tags: android, google-play-services

Just installed a fresh Android Studio and Marshmallow Platform. I tried to run a GCM app and this happens.

`Google Play services out of date. Requires 8487000 but found 8185470`

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You can promt the user to upgrade, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852869

Answer (score 2):

Your phone hasn't auto-updated to Google Play Services 8.4 yet (it only has 8.1), and your app was compiled using Google Play Services 8.4.

Either change the version you are compiling with in the `app/build.gradle` to `8.1.0`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

or wait for your phone to auto-update to the latest version.

Comment: Ah ok. Is there any way to auto-update on the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Google Play Services application. You can use [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) to obtain `Intent` for launching recover process.